# How to correctly instantiate a cube over another, or side-by-side another one

Tags: unity, mathematics

In a Minecraft spawn system like, I can't make works correctly following code.
Specifically, if I use Code 1 it works only when  I instantiate a cube over another one, not one aside other. The opposite if I use Code 2.

Can you help me write correct code to make it works ?

```
void BuildBlock_v2(GameObject block)
{
    Quaternion rotation;
    rotation = Quaternion.Euler(0, 0, 0);

    if (Physics.Raycast(shootingPoint.position, shootingPoint.forward, out RaycastHit hitInfo))
    {

        float playerRotationY = Mathf.Round(shootingPoint.rotation.eulerAngles.y);
        if (playerRotationY >= 0 && playerRotationY < 45)
            rotation = Quaternion.Euler(0, -180, 0);
        else if (playerRotationY >= 45 && playerRotationY < 135)
            rotation = Quaternion.Euler(0, -90, 0);
        else if (playerRotationY >= 135 && playerRotationY < 225)
            rotation = Quaternion.Euler(0, 0, 0);
        else if (playerRotationY >= 225 && playerRotationY <= 315)
            rotation = Quaternion.Euler(0, -270, 0);
        else
            rotation = Quaternion.Euler(0, 0, 0); 

        GameObject hitObject = hitInfo.collider.gameObject;
        if (hitInfo.transform.tag == "Block")
        {
            float height = hitObject.GetComponent<Renderer>().bounds.size.y;
            float y = hitObject.transform.position.y; 
            
            // 
            // Code 1 : works when I instantiate a cube over another one, not one aside other
            //Vector3 spawnPosition = new Vector3(Mathf.RoundToInt(hitInfo.point.x + hitInfo.normal.x / 2), hitInfo.point.y + 0.5f , Mathf.RoundToInt(hitInfo.point.z + hitInfo.normal.z / 2));                
            
            // Code 2: it  works when I instantiate a cube side by side another, but not one over another
            Vector3 spawnPosition = new Vector3(Mathf.RoundToInt(hitInfo.point.x + hitInfo.normal.x / 2), y, Mathf.RoundToInt(hitInfo.point.z + hitInfo.normal.z / 2));
            Instantiate(block, spawnPosition, rotation, parent);

        }
        else if (hitInfo.transform.tag == "Terrain")
        {
            // Instance on ground
            //Vector3 spawnPosition = new Vector3(Mathf.RoundToInt(hitInfo.point.x), Mathf.RoundToInt(hitInfo.point.y)+0.5f, Mathf.RoundToInt(hitInfo.point.z));
            Vector3 spawnPosition = new Vector3(Mathf.RoundToInt(hitInfo.point.x), hitInfo.point.y + 0.5f, Mathf.RoundToInt(hitInfo.point.z));
            Instantiate(block, spawnPosition, rotation, parent);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: If you have 2 versions of code and you have some part of it working, it helps if you write as well how it fails to achieve what you actually want

Comment: Code 1 : works when I instantiate a cube over another one, not one aside other. In this case cube is not "centered" to other cube.. a little upper, a little down.
Code 2:  it  works when I instantiate a cube side by side another, but not one over another.. It instantiate 'inside' other cube, or more over it

Comment: Can you show how your cubes are modeled and how your grid is laid out? I'm confused because it looks like you are using the raycast hit and not the origin of the block the raycast hit. Also, why are you adding the normal?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your blocks are individual game objects with 1 unit of size, they are axis aligned, and the origin of all blocks is at their center:

The raycast.transform.position gives you the origin of the cube that was hit. Raycast.normal gives you the normal direction of the face of the cube the raycast hit. The placement position of the new cube is therefore at old cube position + hit normal * cube size. Assuming cube size of 1, this can be ignored.

I'm on my phone right now so writing code would be difficult. I think this is enough for you to update your code. Let me know if you need more.